# Loading server side relative javascript src from relative path in asp file

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a local IIS server pointing at a virtual workspace at c:\projects

My folder structure inside c:\projects looks like so

```
Game
    src
        asp
            test.asp
    jquery
        jquery.min.js
```

My test.asp file simply looks like:

```
<% @LANGUAGE = JScript %>
<script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl('../../jquery/jquery.min.js') %>" type="text/javascript" language="jscript" runat="server"></script>
Response.Write("Hello World");
```

That is it for now.

Whenever I send a http request to test.asp file a client side javascript file I get an Internal 500 error. However if I remove the jquery script tag from test.asp I successfully see the "Hello World" response on my client side javascript. So I am guessing the 500 error is coming from it not liking my relative path. Or could it be not liking jquery with runat="server"?

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong please?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

You better switch to "~/somepath" instead of "~/../../somepath". "~/" The ~ operator used to specify a root-relative path.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116%28v=vs.140%29.aspx

Comment: So I would use: <script src="<%=ResolveClientUrl('~/game/jquery/jquery.min.js') %>" type="text/javascript" language="jscript" runat="server"></script>   I tried this and got the same error

Comment: Following the link you gave me I got the root path using Server.MapPath("~"). It said the root path was "c:\projects\game\src\asp\~" so surely I can only get to the jquery folder using "../" paths? Thanks again